# What does the $magnet$ hero amp do

Tags: sunset-overdrive

The text says that it will attract "loot" from further away.  Does Loot include ammo crates and health, or is it just money?  I'm trying to decide if I should get this or save up for Chance of Lighting lvl 2.  Thanks.